# Unity c# jsonUtility functions arent working

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

Want to convert a object to a json string and back.

My object:

```
[Serializable]
public class Save
{
    public Levels PlayerLvl { get; set; }
    public int Kills { get; set; }
}
```

function in code:

```
testfunction(Save savedata) {
    //(int)savedata.PlayerLvl equals 1
    //savedata.Kills equals 5
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(savedata);
    debug.log(json) // json equals "{}"
}
```

The same happens when I get a json string and want to convert it back:

```
testFunction(string jsonstring) {
    //jsonstring is a valid json string that equals Save object
    Save savedata = JsonUtility.FromJson<Save>(jsonstring);
    // savedate equals a new Save object without content
}
```

whats wrong here?

---

Edit:

Json that I get:

```
{
    "Kills": 5,
    "PlayerLvl": 1
}
```

Levels enum:

```
public enum Levels {
    Level1 = 1,
    Level2 = 2
}
```

Comment: can you show the ``json`` example and the ``Levels`` class

Comment: afaik JsonUtility doesn't support properties, either use fields or a different library such as Json.NET

Comment: try to add ``[Serializable]``also for ``public enum Levels``

Comment: remove all the get;set; as JsonUtility does not support properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See from [Manual: JSON Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html)

> **Supported types**
>
> The JSON Serializer API supports any `MonoBehaviour` subclass, `ScriptableObject` subclass, or plain class or struct with the `[Serializable]` attribute. When you pass in an object to the standard Unity serializer for processing, the same rules and limitations apply as they do in the Inspector: **Unity serializes fields only**; and types like `Dictionary<>` are not supported.
>
> Unity does not support passing other types directly to the API, such as primitive types or arrays. If you need to convert those, wrap them in a class or struct of some sort.

So you want to remove all `{get; set;}` in order to use fields not properties

```
[Serializable]
public class Save
{
    public Levels PlayerLvl;
    public int Kills;
}
```